# Segmentation fault when running nuttcp inside Docker

Tags: linux-networking, docker, udp, testing, iperf

I am measuring the UDP throughput between two Docker containers that are connected by Docker's native overlay network. I already used `iperf` but also want to measure the throughput with `nuttcp`. But when I am starting the server instance and then start the client instance, the server instance crashes with the following error message: `Segmentation fault (core dumped)`. This is how I started the server:

```
nuttcp -S -u --nofork
```

and this is how I started the client:

```
nuttcp -u -T 115 10.0.0.3
```

The server instance crashes directly after starting up the client. I used the same commands to run `nuttcp` outside of Docker without any problems.

Here is some additional informations about the versions I am using:

```
# inside the container:
$ uname -a
Linux 310d92462ac0 3.19.0-58-generic #64~14.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Fri Mar 18 19:05:43 UTC 2016 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
$ nuttcp -V
nuttcp-6.1.2

# outside the container:
$ uname -a
Linux libAMS 3.19.0-58-generic #64~14.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Fri Mar 18 19:05:43 UTC 2016 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
$ docker -v
Docker version 1.10.3, build 20f81dd
```

Does anyone have an idea how to solve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The bug is in the Version: 6.1.2 of nuttcp
For more information and fix read this link https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=745051

My suggestion is to use a new version.

```
mkdir nuttcp
cd nuttcp/
wget http://nuttcp.net/nuttcp/beta/nuttcp-7.3.3.c
```

If you don’t have gcc

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential manpages-dev
```

compile program and run

```
cc nuttcp-7.3.3.c -o nuttcp-7
./nuttcp-7 –V
nuttcp-7.3.3
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I just solved the problem by downloading the [binary](http://nuttcp.net/nuttcp/nuttcp-7.3.3/nuttcp-7.3.3.x86_64) of the  7.3.3 version directly. So I didn't have to compile anything.